# Dynamic variables in loop

Tags: ruby

I have this working code. I think this must be easier with a while loop.

```
if not c.e1.nil?
  extrapreis = number_to_currency Extra.find(c.e1).aufschlag, :unit=>"EUR "
  array.push Extra.find(c.e1).name + " (" + extrapreis.to_s + ")"
  extpreis = extpreis + Extra.find(c.e1).aufschlag
end
if not c.e2.nil?
  extrapreis = number_to_currency Extra.find(c.e2).aufschlag, :unit=>"EUR "
  array.push Extra.find(c.e2).name + " (" + extrapreis.to_s + ")"
  extpreis = extpreis + Extra.find(c.e2).aufschlag
end
if not c.e3.nil?
  extrapreis = number_to_currency Extra.find(c.e3).aufschlag, :unit=>"EUR "
  array.push Extra.find(c.e3).name + " (" + extrapreis.to_s + ")"
  extpreis = extpreis + Extra.find(c.e3).aufschlag
end
if not c.e4.nil?
  extrapreis = number_to_currency Extra.find(c.e4).aufschlag, :unit=>"EUR "
  array.push Extra.find(c.e4).name + " (" + extrapreis.to_s + ")"
  extpreis = extpreis + Extra.find(c.e4).aufschlag
end
if not c.e5.nil?
  extrapreis = number_to_currency Extra.find(c.e5).aufschlag, :unit=>"EUR "
  array.push Extra.find(c.e5).name + " (" + extrapreis.to_s + ")"
  extpreis = extpreis + Extra.find(c.e5).aufschlag          
end
```

It is always the same code, except for the variable `e` (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`). How can I put this in a while loop and put the counter together with `e`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(1..5).each do |i|
  e = c.send("e#{i}")
  next if e.nil?
  found = Extra.find(e)
  array.push("#{found.name} (#{number_to_currency(found.aufschlag, unit: "EUR ")})")
  extpreis += found.aufschlag
end
```

If you can be certain that `c.e1` etc. never becomes `false`, then:

```
(1..5).each do |i|
  next unless e = c.send("e#{i}")
  found = Extra.find(e)
  array.push("#{found.name} (#{number_to_currency(found.aufschlag, unit: "EUR ")})")
  extpreis += found.aufschlag
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So I learn a little more about rails ;)

Comment: It is not Rails. It's all plain Ruby. Actually, I barely know anything about Rails.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with this untested code:

```
[c.e1, c.e2, c.e3, c.e4, c.e5].each do |e|
  if e
    extrapreis = number_to_currency(Extra.find(e).aufschlag, unit: 'EUR ')
    array << Extra.find(e).name + ' (' + extrapreis.to_s + ')'
    extpreis += Extra.find(e).aufschlag
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe `unless` instead of `if !`?

Comment: I don't like `unless`, especially at the start of a conditional block. It's one of those programmer-choice, often argued, syntax things.

Comment: Fair enough - in fact [this article](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/12/01/unless-the-abused-ruby-conditional/) would advocate a simple `if e` instead :)

Comment: That's true, `if e` is how I'd normally write it if I was doing a refactor or review. :-) I'll adjust it. Thanks.

Comment: You'd probably like [Ruby Best Practices](https://github.com/sandal/rbp-book)

Answer (score 0):

Notes on your code:

- Use of parentheses: Ruby allows you to drop them, but the community seems to have reached a consensus it may harm readability, restrict its usage to DSL-style code.
- `extrapreis`: this may be "private" code (well, it's not anymore since you publicly asked about it), but it's good practice to use the commonly accepted language in the programming world (for script names, variable names, comments, everything).
- `array.push`, `x = x + y`, ...: you may use this but being aware about functional programming and why inplace updates are considered (by some) bad practice. [More on this issue](https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming).
- `if not c.e1.nil?` -> `if c.e1`.
- `Extra.find(c.e1).aufschlag`. In each block you call this twice, why? use a variable to store the value.

---

For a novice programmer a functional approach may be a little difficult to grasp at first, but it introduces important concepts that will (hopefully) prove useful later on:

```
strings, values = [c.e1, c.e2, c.e3, c.e4].compact.map do |e|
  value = Extra.find(e).aufschlag
  extra_price = number_to_currency(value, :unit => "EUR")
  name = Extra.find(e).name 
  ["#{name} (#{extra_price})", value]
end.transpose
extra_price_total = values.inject(0, :+)
```